# How to loop through pandas data frame to make boxplots at once

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, seaborn, boxplot

I have a data frame like this with thousand of entries and I want to make box plot to check the outliers in my data.

| HR | O2Sat | Temp | SBP | DBP | Resp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110.9 | 102.5 | 57.21 | 165.2 | 64.0 | 15.2 |
| 97.0 | 95.0 | 38.72 | 98.0 | 72.0 | 19.0 |
| 89.0 | 99.0 | 45.02 | 112.0 | 62.5 | 22.0 |
| 90.0 | 95.0 | 36.7 | 175.0 | 105.0 | 30.0 |
| 103.0 | 88.5 | 37.47 | 122.0 | 104.0 | 24.5 |

I am using seaborn library to make Boxplots. But I have to write 6 different code lines for each column like this:

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.boxplot(y = 'HR', data = box_df_1) 
sns.boxplot(y = 'O2Sat', data = box_df_1) 
sns.boxplot(y = 'Temp', data = box_df_1) 
sns.boxplot(y = 'SBP', data = box_df_1) 
sns.boxplot(y = 'DBP', data = box_df_1) 
sns.boxplot(y = 'Resp', data = box_df_1)
```

Can someone help me with some code in which Loop is used and a loop will make the boxplots at once using seaborn, and I don't have to write separate line of code for each column?

Regards,
Huzaifa

Comment: `sns.boxplot(data=box_df1.melt(), y='variable', x='value' )` ?

Comment: Thanks JohanC. Can you briefly tell what this melt() function is for?

Comment: See the tutorial [Long-form vs. wide-form data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data)

Comment: Can't you just do `sns.boxplot(data=box_df1)` here? I don't think the long-form transformation is necessary based on the example given.

Comment: Nice. Thank you @mwaskom  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a list for the columns:

```
cols = ['HR', 'O2Sat', 'Temp', 'SBP', 'DBP', 'Resp']
```

iterate over the list

```
for item in cols:     
    sns.boxplot(x = box_df_1[item])
    plt.show()
```